# Online judge showing runtime error

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error, depth-first-search

My code is working fine for all the test cases. Yet, when I submit it to SPOJ, it shows NZEC-runtime error.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/BUGLIFE/

```
def dfs(graph, start, visited = None, parent = None):
    if visited == None:
        visited = set()
        visited.add(start)
    for num in graph[start]:
        if num not in visited:
            visited.add(num)
            if dfs(graph,num,visited,start):
                return True
        else:
            if num != parent:
                return True
    return False
tc = int(raw_input())
for i in range(1, tc+1):
    yo = {}
    s = raw_input()
    n, r = map(int, s.split())
    for j in range(r):
        s = raw_input()
        p, q = map(int, s.split())
        yo[p] = yo.get(p,[]) + [q]
        yo[q] = yo.get(q,[]) + [p]
    start = q
    if dfs(yo, start):
        print "Scenario #%d:" %(i)
        print "Suspicious bugs found!"
    else:
        print "Scenario #%d:" %(i)
        print "No suspicious bugs found!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's caused by stackoverflow. Because test case may have 2000 node.

See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth)